# Chromatic self-maps for almost disjoint families

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $[\omega]^\omega$ denote the collection of infinite subsets of $\omega$. We say that ${\cal A}\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ is an *almost disjoint family* if $A \neq B \in {\cal A}$ implies $|A\cap B|< \aleph_0$.

Let $X\neq\varnothing$ be a set and let ${\cal E}\subseteq {\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ be a collection of non-empty subsets. We say that a map $f: {\cal E}\to X$ is a *chromatic self-map* if

1. $f(e) \in e$ for all $e\in {\cal E}$, and
2. if $e_1\neq e_2 \in {\cal E}$ and $e_1\cap e_2 \neq \varnothing$, then $f(e_1)\neq f(e_2)$.

**Question.** Does every almost disjoint family ${\cal A}\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ have a chromatic self-map?

**Remark.** It suffices to answer the question for maximum almost disjoint families ("MAD families").

Comment: I find your use of the term "self-map" a bit confusing. I guess you mean functions with the property $f(e)\in e$? I'm used to seeing those called choice functions, or selectors. And a "self-map" of a set $S$ is a map $f:S\to S$.

Comment: The map would be injective: if $f(e_1)=f(e_2)=n$ then $n\in e_1\cap e_2$, so by condition 2 you'd get $e_1=e_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If such an $f$ exists then $\mathcal A_n=\{e\in\mathcal A:f(e)=n\}$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint subsets of $\omega$, so $\mathcal A_n$ is countable, so $\mathcal A=\bigcup_n\mathcal A_n$ is countable. So the answer is "no" if $\mathcal A$ is uncountable. Of course it is "yes" if $\mathcal A$ is countable.